# Hibernate auto commit without any DAO request

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-transactions

I'm currently reading code from another guy. I saw that he doesn't make any explicit request to update `DB` but it does update the entity. Please check below `pseudo code`:

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = false)
public void updateFoo(long fooId) {

    // Get foo instance from DB, foo has status = 0
    Foo foo = fooDAO.getFoo(fooId);
    foo.setStatus(1);
    // There is no call to DAO layer from here
}
```

I checked from `My SQL`, `foo` is updated without any `session.save(foo)` or `session.update(foo)`

Normally, I would call some thing like this in `FooDAO` layer

```
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().update(foo);
```

How's that possible? I suspect that the `Transaction` auto `commit` POJO Object. Please let me know how? And why would anyone do that, is this make code harder to read?

Comment: That's the basic principle of JPA/Hibernate. Managed entities are... managed. Their state is persisted automatically. This is idiomatic JPA code. Calling save() or update() would just show that the author doesn't understand how JPA/Hibernate works.

Comment: @JB Nizet: sorry for my lack of understanding, could you let me know: what's the point of call `update()` when it will be updated anyway

Comment: Just read the [javadoc](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#update-java.lang.Object-): *Update the persistent instance with the identifier of the given **detached** instance*. Detached instances, by definition, are not managed. So if you have a detached instance containing modifications, you can update the database by attaching it using the update() method.